# MySQL ordering by int in row

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a MySQL query to get some data out of a table based on how many votes an 'object' has:
`SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY votes DESC` is what I'm using now. However, I want to see where the objects rank, and have a temporary 'ranking' row, so I can grab that integer and use it accordingly.

Thanks.

Edit:

Output:

```
id | name  | votes
2  | Test  | 8
1  | Test2 | 5
```

Wanted output:

```
id | name  | votes | ranking
2  | Test  | 8     | 1
1  | Test2 | 5     | 2
```

Comment: kindly post input and expected output. Also kindly read How to Ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql check this out, this should help you solve the problem